# Interpolate an entire layer's animation in Krita

Tags: animation, krita, interpolation

I'm wondering if it's possible to interpolate a layer's position in the Krita graphics editing and animation tool.

Let’s say I have a picture in position A at frame 1. I want this picture to move smoothly to position B over 10 frames.

I can't re-draw this picture in every single frame, so can I instead tell Krita that after 10 frames I want the picture to be in position B? So that Krita can work out where the picture needs to be in each of the frames 2-9 so that the movement looks smooth?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Krita is a **raster drawing program** in which drawings (used in animations) are rendered on the canvas by reproducing the stored color values in the underlying individual pixels.

Inorder to implement interpolation, a sample of outline points (which are used to encapsulate an animatable object ) need to be identified by the underlying software and then  math operations need to performed , based on the start and end location of the **individual points  of this object's outine** .

This is achieved in **vector drawing programs** like Animate and ToonBoom by employing mathematical formula's which define the outline of the object and  then the change in the position or shape is interpolated by determining the change in these outline values and then interpolating the inbetween values.

However,as Krita is a raster application ,the outline values are just color values stored in individual pixels and the most one can do to these  values is to **change it's color or opacity and therefore no shape or position interpolation is available in Krita.** Krita only provides the ability to interpolate the **opacity** of the layer [as  seen here](https://docs.krita.org/fr/reference_manual/dockers/animation_curve.html)

However,now that Krita is  also providing **Vector graphics  support** , there may be a chance that some time in the future ,shape and position interpolation may become a reality.